# Angular 2, sub-components of dynamic component are not rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, ng-component-outlet

I'm using this method

```
<ng-container
   *ngComponentOutlet="myComponent">
</ng-container>
```

to inject one component into another component, in my case a form into a sidebar. However from the injected component (the form) I cannot use pipes and shared components of the application. No component or pipe present in the shared.module is recognized within the injected component. How can I make shared components available in the component injected through ngComponentOutlet?

**I did it, but**:
I did it using the component factory [angular-comp-factory](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). But actually I have another question:
My component is getting rendered but without its sub-components. How can I render its sub-components using the component factory?

Comment: Would you mind providing some code snippets? A (non-) working example would be great! (e.g. via stackblitz)

Comment: Hi @KenanGüler, i did it using just the built-in component factory of Angular. But actually the question is another one. The sub-components of my dynamic component are not instantiated...

Comment: I see. Glad, you solved your problem! However, AFAIK the component selector a la `<my-component/>` or the [`router-outlet`](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet) is being used in most cases, rather than `ngComponentOutlet` one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed. It was only a problem with the arrangement of the modules.